# reading file from particular line containing some keyword in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to programming please help me.
I need to read a file from particular line based on the time and write the same into another file. But its skipping the first line while writing into the other file.

```
timeStr="2011-08-01 02:24"
File.open(path+ "\\logs\\messages.log", "r") do |f| 
  # Skip the garbage before pattern: 
  while f.gets !~ (/#{timeStr}/) do; end                   
  # Read your data: 
  while l = f.readlines
    File.open(path+ "\\logs\\messages1.log","a") do |file1|
      file1.puts(l)
    end
  end 
end
```

When am running the above script the first line matching timeStr is skipped and from the second line the file is written in to the messages1. when I open messages1.log file the first line containing the matching string will not be present. Any idea how to include the first line also while writing to the messages1.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to keep the line that matches `/#{timeStr}/` but this loop:

```
while f.gets !~ (/#{timeStr}/) do; end
```

throws it away. You could rearrange things a bit:

```rb
# Get `line` in the right scope.
line = nil

# Eat up `f` until we find the line we're looking for
# but keep track of `line` for use below.
while(line = f.gets)
    break if(line =~ /#{timeStr}/)
end

# If we found the line we're looking for then get to work...
if(line)
    # Grab the rest of the file
    the_rest = f.readlines
    # Prepend the matching line to the rest of the file
    the_rest.unshift(line)
    # And write it out.
    File.open(path + "\\logs\\messages1.log","a") do |file1|
        file1.puts(the_rest)
    end
end
```

I haven't tested this but it should work baring typos and the like.

Comment: Hey thanks, its working fine now using the code that you provided :)